# equation or equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

Is a numerical equality (like $1+2 = 3$) an algebraic equation?

In google search we have:
"equation
ɪˈkweɪʒ(ə)n/
noun
noun: equation; plural noun: equations

```
1.
Mathematics
a statement that the values of two mathematical expressions are equal (indicated by the sign =)."
```

In Wikipedia we have:
"In mathematics, an equation is a statement of an equality containing one or more variables."

In Merriam-webster we have:
"
Definition of equation for English Language Learners

```
mathematics : a statement that two expressions are equal (such as $8 + 3 = 11$ or $2x – 3 = 7$)
```

"

Comment: It may be a matter of philosophy, but I would say that $1+2=3$ is an equation.  I might even go so far as to say that it is an *algebraic* equation---typically, algebraic equations are those that involve polynomials, and that is an equation involving three constant polynomials.

Comment: "algebraic equation" is an equality with variables. The equality with constant numbers is an identity. An algebraic equation may also be an identity, e.g. $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.